# How to configure Nginx for URL mapping of CNAME requests?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure my Nginx server block to accept requests without changing the requested domain, so that my users can use their custom domain with my application via a DNS CNAME-type entry.

The expected behaviour is as follows:

- User creates a dns cname entry pointing to my server/domain e.g. `www.userdomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com`
- My server then directs the request to my application `www.mydomain.com/app` while maintaining the URL `www.userdomain.com`

I've been able to make this behaviour work as above by setting my `www.mydomain.com` server block as `default_server`, but i'm trying to find a different way because i want to replicate this behaviour with a different server block/domain in the same server.

My current Server Block looks like the example below:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/mydomain.com/app;
    index index.php;

    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to reproduce this behaviour without setting the `default_server` flag?

Comment: `server_name www.mydomain.com www.userdomain.com;`

Comment: @IvanShatsky in my app the domain `www.userdomain.com` can be arbitrarily set and changed by the user, for this reason i can't set  `www.userdomain.com`  in the server block

Comment: Your options for specifying server name are exact match (highest priority), domain suffix (`*.userdomain.com` or `.userdomain.com`), regex pattern to match (e.g. `~(www\.)?(user1|user2)domain\.com$`, lowest priority). If you can't choose any of those, I'm afraid the `default_server` is your only option, at least without using 3rd party modules.